# Tengo problemas al instalar mis dependencias de proyecto ionic

Tags: nodejs, ionic

Acabo clonar un proyecto de ionic (No lo cree yo es de mi trabjao) y estoy instalando las dependencia es aqui donde tengo problemas para instalarlos, al momento que lo instalo me muestra el siguiente error

[image: Resultado de la instalacion]

Y al momento que hago ionic serve me muestra el siguiente error

[image: Error al instalar las dependencias]

Supongo que tiene que ver con node-gyp, pero no se muy bien que es lo que este pasando, ya intente setear con npm config set tanto python como vs pero sigue si poder instalar las dependencias

Dependencias que estoy usando

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "bowser": "2.1.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-browser": "5.0.1",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.5.2",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.15",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-windows": "^5.0.0",
        "fingerprintjs2": "^1.5.1",
        "foreman": "^2.0.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
        "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "moment": "^2.22.1",
        "rxjs": "5.4.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
```

Realmente no se que dependencia estoy instalando mal o que es lo que puede ser el error, puede ser tambien la version de node que tengo?

Versiones que uso

```
node -v v14.19.3
node-gyp -v v3.6.2

Ionic
   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v14.19.3 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.17
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Tiene esto algo que ver?

Answer (score 0):

Es porque te falta la carpeta Node Modules que no se añade al repositorio para ahorrar espacio, para solucionar tienes que instalarlo.

```
npm install
```

Comment: El error que se muestra en la primera imagen es despues de hacer el npm install